# Talend pass multiple values to output table

Tags: talend

I should get multiple values from 2 connected table. I will pass the filtered value to the output table.

```
    Table A:
         ID=001
         Category='ANIMAL'
    Table B:
         ID=B001
         FAMILY            NAME
         'ANIMAL'          'DOG'
         'ANIMAL'          'CAT'
         'ANIMAL'          'PIG'
```

I have used TOracleInput and TOracleOutput. and Im only getting PIG on my Output Table.....

How should I do it to pass Dog, Cat and Pig on my output table?

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: how have you connected this..can you show a screenshot or some diagram of  your job

Comment: Sorry, I still can't post image. my structure is this, I have OracleInput which has ID and Category, I filter the ID first then, the Category is being connected on the Family of the Second OracleInput, then I connect the Family to the OracleOutput field. Where, Dog, Cat and Pig should be inserted.

Comment: so if i understand correctly you are having as below tOracleInput-->tOracleInput-->tOracleOutput...but you should use tMap to do joining ...so your structure should be tOracleInput1-->tmap(another tOracleInput2 used as lookup to this) and then in tMap take output and move that output to tOracleOutput

Comment: Thank you for the response.Yes. I used tMap to tOracleInput and tOracleOutput but the data that is being stored on the tOracleOutput is the last on the list from tOracleInput.

Comment: ok then it guess problem is how you are joining the two inputs in tmap. You should be doing something like tinput1.column_id joined to toracleinput2.column_id and in properties for join select match model as ALL Matches, join model Inner join or Left ouer join based on your need.

Answer (score 0):

.so your structure should be tOracleInput1-->tmap(another tOracleInput2 used as lookup to this) and then in tMap take output and move that output to tOracleOutput
 problem is how you are joining the two inputs in tmap. You should be doing something like tinput1.column_id joined to toracleinput2.column_id and in properties for join select match model as ALL Matches, join model Inner join or Left ouer join based on your need.